# Get all joined records when one match is found

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

Here's simple test database that should explain my problem:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `articles` VALUES(1, 'first article');
INSERT INTO `articles` VALUES(2, 'second article');

CREATE TABLE `flags` (
  `flag_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `flag_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`flag_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `flags` VALUES(1, 'red');
INSERT INTO `flags` VALUES(2, 'blue');
INSERT INTO `flags` VALUES(3, 'green');
INSERT INTO `flags` VALUES(4, 'orange');
INSERT INTO `flags` VALUES(5, 'purple');

CREATE TABLE `map` (
  `map_article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `map_flag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`map_article_id`,`map_flag_id`),
  KEY `map_flag_id` (`map_flag_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `map` VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO `map` VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO `map` VALUES(2, 2);
INSERT INTO `map` VALUES(2, 3);
INSERT INTO `map` VALUES(1, 4);
```

raw:

```
article_id  article_title
1   first article
2   second article

flag_id     flag_name
1   red
2   blue
3   green
4   orange
5   purple

map_article_id  map_flag_id
1   1
1   2
2   2
2   3
1   4
```

One table with articles, one with flags and one with mapping article-flag.

Selecting all articles with joined flags is easy, and it's working properly:

```
SELECT `article_id` , `article_title` , GROUP_CONCAT( `flag_name` )
FROM `articles`
LEFT JOIN `map` ON `map_article_id` = `article_id`
LEFT JOIN `flags` ON `flag_id` = `map_flag_id`
GROUP BY `article_id`
```

Results are:

```
article_id  article_title   GROUP_CONCAT(`flag_name`)   
1   first article   red,blue,orange
2   second article  blue,green
```

Problem is, I want to find all articles with some specified flag, but with GROUP_CONCAT field intact. When I'm adding WHERE `map_flag_id` = 1 query returns:

```
article_id  article_title   GROUP_CONCAT(`flag_name`)   
1   first article   red
```

How to get only article with red but with all red,blue,orange flags in last column? Please don't suggest "LIKE %red%", I need this to be fast.

thanks

**EDIT**

Maybe?

```
SELECT `article_id` , `article_title` , (

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `flag_name` )
FROM `flags`
LEFT JOIN `map` ON `map_flag_id` = `flag_id`
WHERE `map_article_id` = `article_id`
)

FROM `articles`
LEFT JOIN `map` ON `map_article_id` = `article_id`
LEFT JOIN `flags` ON `flag_id` = `map_flag_id`
WHERE `flag_id` =1
GROUP BY `article_id`
```

Comment: The `LIKE` won't necessarily be slow, when applied in `HAVING`, or `HAVING FIND_IN_SET('red', flags)` since these are both applied after the aggregation is all completed.  Is that performant enough for your needs?  Otherwise, you'd need an additional inner join (possibly 2) prior to aggregation and that would be slower. Your suggested subselect is likely to be slower than all these. It depends on how many grouped article_id would be returned. If it is only a few, `HAVING FIND_IN_SET()` will have no measurable difference. If it is many thousands, it'll be a little slower.

Comment: Sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2071e/4

Comment: The solution in your edit seems to be valid. Alternatively, you may use the original query with this condition `WHERE article_id IN (SELECT map_article_id FROM map WHERE map_flag_id=?)`. Other alternatively, join a second time with `map` and have the condition on that one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the solutions like this:

1.`SELECT`article_id`,`article_title`, GROUP_CONCAT(`flag_name`) AS flags
    FROM`articles
    `LEFT JOIN`map`ON`map_article_id`=`article_id
    `LEFT JOIN`flags`ON`flag_id`=`map_flag_id
    `GROUP BY`article_id
    `HAVING FIND_IN_SET('red', flags)`

1. `SELECT a.article_id , a.article_title , GROUP_CONCAT( f.flag_name ) AS flags
   FROM map m
   JOIN  articles a ON m.map_article_id = a.article_id AND m.map_flag_id=1
   LEFT JOIN map m1 ON m1.map_article_id = a.article_id
   LEFT JOIN flags f ON f.flag_id = m1.map_flag_id

   GROUP BY a.article_id `